# What Christmas traditions have roots in Jewish traditions?

Tags: christmas

There are many traditions in modern Christmas celebrations, that Jesus would not be familiar with.

What Christmas traditions have their roots in Jewish celebrations, that Jesus would recognize?

Comment: Considering the fact that in the Roman Catholic Church, the Christmas season extends from December 25 to February 2 (Feast of the Presentation) inclusively, your question may be a bit broad. There is also the Feast of Epiphany (January 6), the obscure Feast of the Finding of the Child Jesus in the Temple (January 7) and The Baptism of Jesus (January 13) to name  just a few examples.

Answer (score 2):

The **Feast of the Circumcision of Jesus** is a Christian celebration of the circumcision of Christ in accordance with Jewish tradition.

This [feast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_of_the_Circumcision_of_Christ) is celebrated by Catholics who follow the Extraordinary Rite of the Mass on January 1st. The feast is celebrated on the octave day of Christmas, thus concluding the ancient tradition of celebrating major feast days (Christmas, Easter and Pentecost) for eight days.  This is also the day that Jesus received his **Most Holy Name**.

There is also the [Feast of the Holy Name of Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_of_the_Holy_Name_of_Jesus) , which is celebrated on another date than on January 1st in the Roman Catholic Church.

> The Feast of the Holy Name of Jesus is a feast of the liturgical year celebrated by a number of Christian denominations, on varying dates. In Roman Catholicism the month of January is traditionally dedicated to the Holy Name of Jesus.
>
> In the Latin Rite Catholic Church it is observed as an optional memorial on 3 January by Catholics following the present General Roman Calendar. Franciscans, Carmelites, and Augustinians kept the feast on 14 January; Dominicans on 15 January; in some localities the date was 8 January, in others 31 January, in some localities in Great Britain on 7 August. The Society of Jesus, i.e., the Jesuits, celebrates the Holy Name of Jesus on 3 January as the order's own titular feast.

Answer (score 2):

The season of Advent, which begins four Sundays prior to Christmas, is observed by a number of Protestant denominations as well as the Roman church.  During Advent the Scripture describing the ministry of John the Baptist is frequently read in churches that observe the season.  John is a transitional figure bridging Judaism and Christianity and the Jews who came to repentance under his ministry were no doubt familiar with the words of the Prophets looking forward to the coming Messiah.

In the same way the Jews looked forward to coming of Messiah, Advent looks forward to the Second Coming of Jesus.  It could be argued that Advent is a Christian season that looks back to the expectation the Jewish people had towards Messiah's appearing and forward to His return.

While Jesus would not have been familiar with Advent proper, He certainly knew of the Jews' longing for the appearance of their Messiah.  Advent is the Christian form of that same longing,